# How to insert multiple rows from datagridview to SQL database in VB.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have made a Form named `form1.vb`.
I have 4 TextBoxes named `supid`, `supname`, `supmobile`, `suploc`.
I have a DataGridView named `datagridview1`.
I am transferring these 4 TextBoxes data in the DataGridView but when I try to send a DataGridView row in SQL database, it sends only 1 row.

I want multiple rows inserted in SQL server at once when I click the insert button.
There are many tutorials about C language but no tutorial about `VB.Net`.
Please help how to do this in `VB.Net`.

My code:

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    If TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("PLEASE FILL ALL FIELDS")
    Else
        connection.Open()
        Dim thequery As String = "select*from supplierdata where supmobile = @supmobile"
        Dim cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(thequery, connection)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supmobile", TextBox3.Text)

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.HasRows Then
            MessageBox.Show("MOBILE NO IS ALREADY REGISTERED")
        Else
            reader.Close()
            command = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO supplierdata VALUES (@supid,@supname,@supmobile,@suploc)", connection)
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                command.Parameters.Add("supid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).value
                command.Parameters.Add("supname", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                command.Parameters.Add("supmobile", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                command.Parameters.Add("suploc", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value

                i = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next

            MessageBox.Show("CUSTOMER REGISTERED SUCCESFULLY")
            connection.Close()
            command.Dispose()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hello sir i am new here and i have posted first time here. if you can then pls guide.

Comment: As I said, the answer was provided elsewhere. I will say here what I said there. You should should be using a data adapter and a `DataTable`. Call `Fill` on the data adapter to populate the `DataTable` and bind it to the grid. Saving the changes is then a matter of calling `Update` on the data adapter. Of course, you'll need to configure it first, so you should read up on how to do that. I provided [this link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872) last time where you could learn how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. in your first If statement use `OrElse` instead of `Or`. This will stop the evalution as soon as a True is detected.
2. Keep your connections local. They should be opened at the last minute and closed and disposed as soon as posible. A `Using...End Using` block will take care of that.
3. If all you need is the count then ask for just the count. Don't retrieve data that you don't use. No `DataReader` necessary. Just use `ExecuteScalar`.
4. Good job using Parameters!
5. The names of your parameters that you use in your Sql query must match your names when you add the parameters. (Not true for Access where the order of parameter addition is the only thing that matters.)
6. Now to the real problem `Dim i As Integer = 0` Then you use `DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value` in the For Each loop. Row is always the first row and it never changes in your loop. That is why "it sends only 1 row"
7. You don't want to keep adding parameters in your `For Each` loop.
8. One more thing - If `subid` is an auto-increment column do not send any data for this column.

Untested code. I don't have your form or your database.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode2()
    If TextBox2.Text = "" OrElse TextBox3.Text = "" OrElse TextBox4.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("PLEASE FILL ALL FIELDS")
        Return
    End If
    Dim count As Integer
    Try
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Dim thequery As String = "select Count(*) from supplierdata where supmobile = @supmobile;"
            Using cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(thequery, cn)
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supmobile", TextBox3.Text)
                cn.Open()
                count = CInt(cmd1.ExecuteScalar())
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception 'You probably want to catch more specific exceptions
        'and handle them separately
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    If count > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("MOBILE NO IS ALREADY REGISTERED")
        Return
    End If
    Try
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cmd2 As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO supplierdata (supid,supname,supmobile,suploc)VALUES (@supid,@supname,@supmobile,@suploc)", cn)
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@supid", SqlDbType.Int)
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@supname", SqlDbType.NChar)
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@supmobile", SqlDbType.NChar)
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@suploc", SqlDbType.NChar)
                cn.Open()
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                    With cmd2
                        .Parameters("@supid").Value = row.Cells(0).Value
                        .Parameters("@supname").Value = row.Cells(1).Value
                        .Parameters("@supmobile").Value = row.Cells(2).Value
                        .Parameters("@suploc").Value = row.Cells(3).Value
                    End With
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
            End Using 'You probably want to catch more specific exceptions
            'and handle them separately
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception 'You probably want to catch more specific exceptions
        'and handle them separately
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    MessageBox.Show("CUSTOMER REGISTERED SUCCESFULLY")
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
If `supid` is an auto-increment column remove it form the parameters.
Change Insert query to
`"INSERT INTO supplierdata (supname,supmobile,suploc)VALUES (@supname,@supmobile,@suploc)"`
Then you need to delete the lines
`cmd2.Parameters.Add("@supid", SqlDbType.Int)`
and
`.Parameters("@supid").Value = row.Cells(0).Value`
Do this only if `supid` is and auto-increment (identity column)

Comment: hello sir your code is working fine and inserting all datagridview rows in sql databse .it just  gives error before entering data  " THE PARAMETERIZED QUERY'(SUPID INT, @SUPNAME NCHAR(4000),@SUPMOBILE NCHAR(4000),@SUPLOC' EXPECTS THE PARAMETER '@SUPID, WHICH WAS NOT SUPPLIED.

Comment: If you corrected the code to exclude supid (if it was an auto-increment) please see my edit.

Comment: i have not set auto incremnet for @supid in sql database. now i have added a line before code on error resume next and it is working fine without giving error.